# In swift, how can I have rows (with buttons on them), in a prototype cell, push to different view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am fairly new to swift and Xcode, but am very familiar with other object oriented languages.

[Here is my code to display three rows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUL2E.png)

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UlTableView) —> Int { 
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections 
    return 1 
} 
override func tableView(tableView: UlTableView, numberOfRowslnSection section: Int) —> Int { 
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows 
    return verseData.count 
} 
override func tableView(tableView: UlTableView, cellForRowAtlndexPath indexPath: NSlndexPath) 
    —> UITableViewCell { 
        let cellOne = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("VerseOneCell", forindexPath: indexPath) 
        let verseOne = verseData[indexPath.row] cellOne.textLabel?.text = verseOne.type 
        return cellOne
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hX50H.png) is what is displayed. Each of the three topics have buttons on them, but I want each to have their own view controller. I have three separate view controllers set up on my story board, but when I run it, pressing each topic is taken to the same view controller.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question and paste your code as text. (Indent 4 spaces to format as code.)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you just want to be able to select the row (i.e. no need for a button).

You can either

- ctrl-drag from the cell to a new view controller in storyboard and configure your view controller in `prepareForSegue`

or

- implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` where you would check `indexPath.row` to check which row was selected.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is

`UITableView - didselectrowatindexpath` and from there, find the indexPath.row and performsegue depending on what row it is